# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'vkbot.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python, django

При запуске сервера *python manage.py runserver* выдает ошибку:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 13, 2023 - 15:04:26
Django version 4.1.4, using settings 'vkbot.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\Desktop\Projects\Python\Bots\BibikaBot\vkbot\wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env"))
AttributeError: module 'dotenv' has no attribute 'read_dotenv'. Did you mean: 'load_dotenv'?

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 32, in import_string    
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Module "vkbot.wsgi" does not define a "application" attribute/class

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 157, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", 
line 31, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 78, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'vkbot.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

**settings.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'm&!s@8am7b!@e(pl6qt7(os^bqje9-bqhmk()yokj*hr2s-!5a'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vkbot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vkbot.wsgi.application'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

BOT_NAME = os.environ['BOT_NAME']
GROUP_ID = os.environ["GROUP_ID"]
BOT_TOKEN = os.environ["GROUP_TOKEN"]
USER_TOKEN = os.environ["USER_TOKEN"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Vkbot.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]